# Parallel Computing in R : how to use the cores

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, parallels, parallel-foreach

I am currently trying parallel computing in R.
I am trying to train a logistic ridge model , and I currently have 4 Cores on my computer. I would like to split my data set equally into 4 pieces, and use each core to train model (on the training data) and save the result of each core into a single vector . the problem is that i have no clue how to do it, right now I tried to parallel with the foreach package, but the problem is the each core sees the same training data. here is the code with the foreach package (which doesn't split the data) :

```
library(ridge)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)

num_of_cores <- detectCores()
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
data_per_core <- floor(nrow(mydata)/num_of_cores)
result <- data.frame()

r <- foreach(icount(4), .combine = cbind) %dopar% {
      result <- logisticRidge(admit~ gre + gpa + rank,data = mydata)
      coefficients(result)
}
```

any idea how to simultaneously split the data into x chunks and train the models in parallel ?

Comment: Are you bound to `parallel` and `foreach`? or are you ok with a `snowfall`-solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this? It uses `snowfall` instead of the `foreach`-library, but should give the same results.

```
library(snowfall)
library(ridge)

# for reproducability
set.seed(123)
num_of_cores <- parallel::detectCores()
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
data_per_core <- floor(nrow(mydata)/num_of_cores)

# we take random rows to each cluster, by sampleid
mydata$sampleid <- sample(1:num_of_cores, nrow(mydata), replace = T)

# create a small function that calculates the coefficients
regfun <- function(dat) {
  library(ridge) # this has to be in the function, otherwise snowfall doesnt know the logistic ridge function
  result <- logisticRidge(admit~ gre + gpa + rank, data = dat)
  coefs <- as.numeric(coefficients(result))
  return(coefs)
}

# prepare the data
datlist <- lapply(1:num_of_cores, function(i){
  dat <- mydata[mydata$sampleid == i, ]
})

# initiate the clusters
sfInit(parallel = T, cpus = num_of_cores)

# export the function and the data to the cluster
sfExport("regfun")

# calculate, (sfClusterApply is very similar to sapply)
res <- sfClusterApply(datlist, function(datlist.element) {
  regfun(dat = datlist.element)
})

#stop the cluster
sfStop()

# convert the list to a data.frame. data.table::rbindlist(list(res)) does the same job
res <- data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(res), ncol = num_of_cores)))
names(res) <- c("intercept", "gre", "gpa", "rank")
res
# res
# intercept          gre
# 1 -3.002592 1.558363e-03
# 2 -4.142939 1.060692e-03
# 3 -2.967130 2.315487e-03
# 4 -1.176943 4.786894e-05
# gpa         rank
# 1  0.7048146997 -0.382462408
# 2  0.9978841880 -0.314589628
# 3  0.6797382218 -0.464219036
# 4 -0.0004576679 -0.007618317
```

Comment: thank you for the answer  ! however I am trying to simulate a situation where the data sits on different machines , therefor I would like to ask if it is possible to export only parts of the data to each cluster and not the whole data set ?  another question is if anyone know how to implement the solution with parallel package (i am not bound to foreach, but cannot use snowfall) ?

Comment: I edited the answer, now don't send the whole dataset to each slave, but only the subset. Still, its a snowfall-solution. May I ask why you cannot use snowfall?

Comment: I get an error when running your example now because, although you're not sending `mydata` to the workers, you're still referring to `mydata` in the worker function.

Comment: You're right, I must've forgotten to check the function, it's now corrected! Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: first of all, thanks a lot for the help david ! I was mistaken to think snowfall can't run on OSX , so I can actually use your code. again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The `itertools` package provides a number of functions for iterating over various data structures with foreach loops. In this case, you could use the `isplitRows` function to split the data frame row-wise into one *chunk* per worker:

```
library(ridge)
library(doParallel)
library(itertools)

num_of_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(num_of_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

r <- foreach(d=isplitRows(mydata, chunks=num_of_cores),
             .combine = cbind, .packages="ridge") %dopar% {
  result <- logisticRidge(admit~ gre + gpa + rank, data = d)
  coefficients(result)
}
```

`isplitRows` also takes a `chunkSize` argument if you want to control the maximum size of each chunk.

Note that using this technique, each worker only receives an appropriate fraction of `mydata`. This is particularly important for larger data frames with a `PSOCK` cluster.

Comment: Steve, thank you very much too,  your code made it simple !

Comment: Thanks! This helps!  The `foreach` nested vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf) still mentions `doNWS` as the only way to do chunking, but that package doesn't seem to exist anymore.  Perhaps you could revise the vignette it in the next `foreach` release?